# How to display list items as columns preserving the left-to-right order?

Tags: css, list, multiple-columns, flexbox

Is it possible in pure CSS to lay out list elements to arbitrary number of columns, preserving the left-to-right order, as on this example?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @martic, thank you for your edit. I couldn't add an image myself due to my low reputation. :)

Comment: Basically, **no**. `flexbox` would allow you to have columns that wrap etc but the order would have to be changed manually. This would be best left to Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be theoretically possible.

- Since you want the flex items arranged in columns,

  ```css
  #flex-container { flex-flow: column wrap; }
  ```
- But then the order of the elements would be preserved vertically (in columns). Since you want horizontally, they must be reordered:

  ```css
  #flex-container > :nth-child(4n - 2) { order: 1; }
  #flex-container > :nth-child(4n - 1) { order: 2; }
  #flex-container > :nth-child(4n - 0) { order: 3; }
  ```
- And then we must force column breaks.

  According to [10. Fragmenting Flex Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#pagination) and [CSS Fragmentation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-break-3/), line breaks can be forced with [`break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before):

  ```css
  #flex-container > :nth-child(-n + 4) {
    page-break-before: always; /* CSS 2.1 syntax */
    break-before: always;  /* New syntax */
  }
  ```

  However, forced breaks in flexbox are not widely implemented yet. It works on Firefox, though.

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
#flex-container > :nth-child(4n - 2) { order: 1; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(4n - 1) { order: 2; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(4n - 0) { order: 3; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(-n + 4) {
  page-break-before: always; /* Old syntax */
  break-before: always;  /* New syntax */
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it actually works, at least the first part:
[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/warMdL). `break-before` seem not to have any effect though (tested on the latest Chrome). Thank you, @Oriol!

Comment: @Peter Yes, we will have to wait until browsers implement the `break-*` properties.