# No extra spacing between items in rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am using the new flexbox CSS module to try and create two columns of boxes.

Goals:
Boxes must go in left-right-left-right etc order, not in column order (row required)
Boxes can be of varied heights
Boxes should have no vertical spacing between them other than what is specified via css

I have accomplished all but the last one on that list.  No matter what I do, if an item in one of the rows is taller than the other, it inevitably pushes the items in the next row down.  I do not want this behavior, and again, using column instead of row is not an option.

Here's some simplified markup you can play with:

HTML:

```
<div class="blocks">
     <div class="block"></div>
     <div class="block"></div>
     <div class="block"></div>
     <div class="block"></div>
     <div class="block"></div>
     <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blocks {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
    width: calc(50% - 15px);
    background: gray;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block:nth-child(2n+1){
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.block:nth-child(1) {
    height: 150px;
}

.block:nth-child(2) {
    height: 190px;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
    height: 180px;
}

.block:nth-child(4) {
    height: 160px;
}

.block:nth-child(5) {
    height: 190px;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
    height: 150px;
}
```

In this examples, there should never be more than 10px of spacing between items in columns.

Here is a JS Fiddle for you guys to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/esryrk3w/

Note the extra vertical spacing between items in columns.

Comment: have a look at this link may be this could help you http://www.jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/

Comment: No jQuery plugins or anything other than CSS solutions please.  This is already running on a fairly complicated AngularJS implementation that doesn't need to be cluttered with a ton of third party plugins. Sorry :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display list items as columns preserving the left-to-right order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30912667/1529630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution? Stop using flexbox.

Just use alternating floats.  The first one floats the second box and every second box after to the right, and the second one floats the first box and every second one after to the left.  Problem Solved.

```
.block:nth-child(2n+2) {

    // POSITIONING
    float: right;
}

.block:nth-child(2n+1) {

    // POSITIONING
    float: left;
}
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/esryrk3w/1/