# How to create both rows and columns in css (or flexbox)?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there any way to align responsive divs using both rows and columns in either flexbox or css like so:

[image]

Because of the ordering (and a mobile breakpoint), I can't simply do columns and because of the slight offsets, rows don't really work.

Should note that when resized for mobile, it should stack on top based on the numbered order.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: which framework are you using ?

Comment: No framework. Just a static one-page done in HTML and CSS.

Comment: I don't think its possible with just css

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the elements in columns, and on mobile use `display: contents`. It is not widely supported yet, though.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
}
.column {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item {
  background: #66D8A4;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.column:first-child > :last-child, .column:last-child > :first-child {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column {
    display: contents;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item" style="order:1">1</div>
    <div class="item" style="order:4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item" style="order:2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item" style="order:3">3</div>
    <div class="item" style="order:5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way would be not using wrappers for the columns, and using `break-*` properties to force column breaks. I explained this technique in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30916008/1529630). However, no browser seems to support this yet.

Comment: Great answer but order is not working on chrome small window size.

Comment: @NenadVracar I think Chrome does not support `display: contents` yet. You can try it on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 3 columns using flexbox. Then nest your additional panels within those columns.

Chances are you can't do this in pure css and will have to resort to some form of JavaScript library (something like https://golden-layout.com)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. The only problem is when it resizes for mobile, it has to stack in the numbered ordered on top of each other.

Comment: You may want to update your question to be more specific about the mobile stacking constraint. Chances are you'll be voted down for not being specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution would to use mansory plugin  http://masonry.desandro.com/ to layout your divs and specify breakpoints using the plugin modules ,however since you prefer flexbox style css probably this link would shead more light on that http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a use case Flexbox was designed for. The upcoming CSS Grid Layout specification is designed for two dimensional layout like this.

Until that lands in browsers you might be better looking at older methods to achieve this. The [Susy Grid](http://susy.oddbird.net/) is worth a look for doing this sort of thing, I've been testing it while working on Grid Layout examples as an example of the sorts of things people want to do with grids in CSS.