# How can i apply CSS on 1st column of each 4*4 grid

Tags: css

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">col lg 4</div>
</div>
```

How can i apply CSS on 1st column of each 4*4 grid

I try this

`.row div:nth-child(4n+0) {
            margin-left: 0px;
 }`

Note: I need only CSS solution for this

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRGR7.jpg)

Comment: Where is your HTML? How can we help you without seeing it?

Comment: Seems to be *nth-child(4n - 0)* based on this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912667/how-to-display-list-items-as-columns-preserving-the-left-to-right-order?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
float:left;
height:100px;
width:25%;
background-color:pink;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
div:nth-child(4n-3) {
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
```

Comment: use this :nth-child(4n-3)

Answer (score -1):

Use "First-child" Pseudo class

**CSS Codes**

```
 div p:first-child{
        color:red;
     }
```

**HTML codes**

```
<div>
     <p>first </p>
     <p>second</p>
     <p>third </p>
     <p>fourth </p>
  </div>    
  <div>
     <p>first </p>
     <p>second</p>
     <p>third </p>
     <p>fourth </p>
  </div>
  <div>
     <p>first </p>
     <p>second</p>
     <p>third </p>
     <p>fourth </p>
  </div>
```

it will change the color of only first paragraph.